# XQuery cannot select children by element name, can select by index

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have an XQuery query where I create an XHTML document out of data stored in XML. The XML looks like this:

```
<document>
    <div>
        <head>name-I-should-display</head>
        <!-- more data -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <head>name-of-div-2</head>
        <!-- more data -->
    </div>
    <!-- more divs -->
</document>
```

In my xquery, I can retrieve the XML document fine:

```
let $mydoc := doc("my-xml-file.xml")
```

I can get the "document" node like this:

```
let $rootnode := $mydoc/*[1]
```

but if I try this:

```
let $rootnode := $mydoc/document
```

I get nothing. When I get the "document" node with the first form, the divs behave the same way. I'm very new to XQuery but I know this should work as it already had in another query on a document with a very similar structure.

Additional information that could help:

- used program is BaseX 9.0.2 on linux
- I'm using the `/name()` function to determine whether or not I have retrieved the node I wanted to or retrieved null
- the XML file has an XSLT stylesheet declaration at the beginning, the similar file that had worked this way didn't have one
- I cannot modify the XML file

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you try `let $rootnode := $mydoc/*[name()='document']`?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, try `let $rootnode := $mydoc/*[local-name()='document']`. If that works (and `name()` doesn't), you most likely have a default namespace you're not showing in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the XML document also an XHTML document in the XHTML namespace? If so, then your XPath is failing because it only selects elements without a namespace. Try:

```
let $rootnode := $mydoc/*:document
```

The asterisk in this instance wildcards the namespace, but not the element name. If that selects the root, then the element is in a namespace. You can discover the URI of the namespace using this:

```
fn:namespace-uri-from-QName($mydoc/*/fn:node-name(.))
```

Then you can take that value and assign it to a prefix in the prolog of your XQuery (This example assumes the output is the XHTML namespace):

```
declare namespace xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/html";
```

Using the prefix, you can select the elements you want using XPath more specifically:

```
let $rootnode := $mydoc/xh:document
```

Comment: The associated XSLT stylesheet was in the XHTML namespace, but the XML file itself isn't in any namespace. Trying out an exact replica of the document but without the the stylesheet association didn't work, but the `$mydoc/*:document` approach worked. Maybe after all there is some namespace magic going on in the background that I just didn't notice because of my lack of experience with this tech.